# How to suppress printer warnings in VBA macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my Word Macro VBA code, I have the following command.

```
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wDoc.PrintOut
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Despite this, I get the printer warning of the picture that says:
"Margins are too tight. Some of the content could be cut during the print. Do you want to print anyway?"

Consider that I cannot change margins because I need them in this way. I would like to avoid this warning message or, alternatively, to answer automatically "yes".

[image]

Comment: Please, refer this: [How to get rid of the Your Margins Are Pretty Small Warning?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/how-to-get-rid-of-the-your-margins-are-pretty/71d27fd0-fcca-4dfa-8702-2284f74080cc)

Comment: https://windowsreport.com/margins-are-pretty-small-error/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `SendKeys` to hit ENTER for you:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wDoc.PrintOut
Sleep 2000
SendKeys("~")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Bad idea. Some portion of document will not be visible (is out of printable area).